# Finding the coefficient on the $x$ term of ${\prod_{n = 1}^{20}(x-n)}.$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

I am trying to find the coefficient on the $x$ term of $\displaystyle{\prod_{n = 1}^{20}(x-n)}$. The issue is that the binomial theorem can't be applied since our $b$ value is changing from term to term. Is there any simple way to do this problem, perhaps a way to change the expression so that the binomial theorem applies? I've tried to do that, and tried looking for a pattern on similar expressions, but I haven't come up with anything. Any help you might have would be appreciated.

Comment: It will be the 19th elementary symmetric polynomial in your roots. See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial for symmetric polynomials.

Comment: A concept popularly known as sum of roots of a polynomial can be of help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The coefficient is given by $$\sum_{k=1}^{20}\prod_{n\not=k\atop n=1,\dots,20}{(-n)}=-\sum_{k=1}^{20}\frac{20!}{k}=-20! H_{20}$$
where $H_k$ is the $k$-th Harmonic number. Those can be looked up in tables (see [A001008](http://oeis.org/A001008) and [A002805](http://oeis.org/A002805)): $H_{20}=\frac{55835135}{15519504}$ and thus the coefficient is given by $-8752948036761600000$.

Comment: This answer just gets better and better on a moment-by-moment basis!  Thanks for adding the value of $H_{20}$!

Comment: Just a question, is there a simple way to calculate the constant of the expanded form?

Comment: @Dominik, Also, I'm not sure how you got your first expression. Could you please explain that

Comment: You get terms with a single power in $x$ from the product $\prod_{n=1}^{20}(x-n)$ by taking $19$ non-$x$ factors and one $x$. The sum is the sum over the different choices of those non-$x$ and $x$ factors. More formally you could try to prove that $(-1)^{N+1} N! H_{N}$ is the $x$-coefficient of $\prod_{n=1}^N (x-n)$ by induction.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Comment: The coefficient must be less than $-20!$, so this can't be correct?

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on it, but this answer is incorrect; the coefficient of $x^{19}$ is in fact $-\sum_{n = 1}^{20} n = -(20 \times 21)/2 = -210$; for the coefficient of $x$, see the answer given by Dominik.  I do believe it is correct.

Comment: @RobertLewis: Unfortunately no 'Med' time for me this morning...

Comment: @Robert Lewis. Shoot! You're right! I'll remove everything but the vieta's formula link.

Comment: @Avi Steiner:  well done!  Glad we got it right!

Comment: @copper.hat:  hooefully on Sunday soon I'll see you for "Meds"!  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to just use Maclaurin's formula:
$$
f(x) = f(0) + \frac{f'(0)}{1!} x + \ldots
$$
In this case:
\begin{align}
f'(x) 
  &= \sum_{1 \le n \le m} \prod_{\substack{1 \le k \le m\\k \ne n}} (x - k) \\
f'(0)
  &= (-1)^{m - 1} m! H_m
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

A generalization to other coefficients (and limits different from $20$) is given in the generating functions of Stirling numbers of the first kind, Pochammer symbols:

$$(x)_n:=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x-k)=\sum_{k=0}^n s(n,k)x^k.$$

Answer (score 1):

The question has been well answered by others. However, I would like to point out that this polynomial has a name---Wilkinson's polynomial---and its own [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson%27s_polynomial). It was put forward by Wilkinson as an example of an apparently innocuous polynomial with remarkable numerical-analytic properties.

Comment: This polynomial is a lot more interesting than I thought! Thanks for giving me a name to google.

Answer (score 0):

The coefficients are the Stirling numbers of the first kind :

[image]